# How to handle datasets with multiple attributes in meta learning?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, meta-learning, metadata, few-shot-learning

So far we have seen a meta-learning example with an image dataset (e.g., Omniglot) that has only one attribute. However, they have multiple attributes if we want to use non-image datasets (e.g., diabetes prediction based on IoT sensors). If we want to generate tasks based on various datasets with different attributes, there is no good reference. How to convert that into the n-way k-shot format with multiple attributes?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.